# Titanium Appcelerator: Loading heavy UI in different thread

Tags: multithreading, titanium, appcelerator

I'm working on my first Titanium application. Right now I'm testing it on Android. I have to update couple of scrollviews from json data.

Is there anyway of using some kind of threading in titanium to keep the UI responsive while my views are loaded. I keep getting these messages.

```
[INFO] :   Choreographer: Skipped 191 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[INFO] :   Choreographer: Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Probably they are alright but it will break the application if data gets heavier.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have access to threading by default in Titanium.

Try not displaying the scrollview on the screen until you have built the UI completely, then call show. This means that it can draw the view once when everything is together.

Also what are you displaying in the scrollView, we need more information here? Why are you using ScrollView and not a tableView? If it's tabular data that's quite simple, and you have many 1000's of rows try looking into the inflexible but performant ListView control which is essentially an optimised TableView.

This may also help: http://www.slideshare.net/omorandi/titanium-mobile-flexibility-vs-performance-13102557

Answer (score 0):

@Muqeet: I was having the same issue with my Android / Titanium app. My choreographer was skipping 300+ frames. I stumbled upon this [nugget from Titanium docs here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow)

> Improved Table Performance (Android)
>
> If you are experiencing performance issues on Android when using custom rows, you can try setting the className property. The class name serves as a cue for reusing the underlying views used to display the rows.
>
> A given className value indicates a row with a particular set of child views. All rows that share a class name must have the same set of children -- for example, the class name "myCustomRow" could identify a row containing two labels and an image view.

Here is a sample code where I changed the row class to className.

```
<Alloy>
<!--TableViewRow class="row" dataId="" details = "" isComplete = "" title="" id="rowView"-->
<TableViewRow className="row" dataId="" details = "" isComplete = "" title="" id="rowView">
    <View class="viewCircle" id="viewCircle">
        <Label class="lblPlayer" id="lblPlayer"></Label>    
    </View>
    <Label class="title" id="lblTitle"/>
</TableViewRow>
```

As you can see, my row has another view and two labels. Now, I am not getting this warning anymore and my tableview is loading 30-45 rows without any problems. My tableview responds faster and feels snappier.

Frankly, I had given up on trying to solve this problem after googling around. Hope this helps other folks. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think best practice now is to use a  instead of a  if you have any size of data. Performance has been mentioned as a specific reason as to why you should use  instead of  ;-)